# Spring Boot with Hibernate APPLICATION FAILED TO START

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

When I start my Spring Boot application, I got that:

2020-11-11 03:02:24.333  WARN 20648 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2020-11-11 03:02:24.335  INFO 20648 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-11-11 03:02:24.486  INFO 20648 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-11-11 03:02:24.489 ERROR 20648 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Action:

Consider the following:
If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

My pom.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>Netcracker-teamproject-2020</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.10</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.0.jre11-preview</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.23.1-GA</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Could you tell me please what should I do to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Just use application.properties file to set up datasource url

```
spring:
    datasource:
        url: 'jdbc:mssql://localhost:5432/dbname'
        username: username
        password: password
```

Comment: That should be it!

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved that, just by adding

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

to the Spring Boot application.properties

Answer (score 0):

My config file:

```
package com.projectparty.config;

import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .driverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
                .url("jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:51264")
                .username("admin")
                .password("admin")
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager
                = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());

        return transactionManager;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty(
                "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty(
                "hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.SQLServerDialect");

        return hibernateProperties;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused for a variety of reasons. In your case, I see that you  chose JDBC connection "`<artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>`", instead of Hikara connection pool.

Spring boot 2+ uses HikaraCP by default. So, the dependency for HikariCp is on your class path "invoked by spring auto configurtion". To fix this, you may try excluding Hikari datasource, by adding the below to your pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Solution 2 is to not use JDBC "datasource type", use Hikara. Sample Hikari config props.

```
###
# HikariCP Properties
###

spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=60000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=200
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=30
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=3000
spring.datasource.hikari.poolName=HikariCP
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource



spring.datasource.hikari.jdbcUrl=**data source url**
spring.datasource.hikari.username=**username**
spring.datasource.hikari.password=**password**
spring.datasource.hikari.driverClassName=com.mssqlOrSomethingElse.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: I've done all the tips you gave me, sadly, nothing changed...

Comment: Moreover, no matter I change smth in pom.xml, HibernateConfig file or use Hikari, the result is the same